# Bar graph showing proportion of bars and restaurants bought red blend

Tags: r, bar-chart

I'm trying to create a bar graph that shows the proportion of restaurants and the proportion of bars that bought the red blend.

I've tried this code:

`ggplot(PCsUnlimited) + stat_summary(aes(x = region, y = totdol), fun = "mean", geom = "bar") + ylab("Avg. total dollars spent")`

I believe the function being used is incorrect, but I'm not sure how I can get the bar graph to add up the number values in the red_blend column.

Comment: Could you add the result of `dput(head(PCsUnlimited,10))` editing your question?

Answer (score 0):

Without any data and a not so clear desired output, we can start from here:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
PCsUnlimited %>%
  group_by(customer_type) %>%
  summarise( perc_red_blend = round(n_distinct(customer_id[red_blend > 0])/n_distint(customer_id)*100,2)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = customer_type, y = perc_red_blend)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity')
```